# Iphone JSON-Framework EOF Error

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, json, json-framework

I'm attempting to use Json-Framework to parse output (on the iPhone) from my website.  The data on the website is an array of news objects... passed through PHP's json_encode().

The JSON Output is here: http://pastebin.com/Be429nHx

I am able to connect to the server and store the JSON data, then I do:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Create a dictionary from the JSON string
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];

NSArray *items = [results valueForKeyPath:@"data.array"];
NSLog(@" NewsID : %@", [[items objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"newsID"]);
```

and I receive the following error from the NSLog() line:

```
-JSONValue failed. Error is: Didn't find full object before EOF
Event Id : (null)
STATE: <SBJsonStreamParserStateStart: 0x4e3c960>
JSONValue failed. Error is: Token 'key-value separator' not expected before outer-most array or object
Event Id : (null)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated... thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried the NSASCIIStringEncoding?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not familiar with it.  Robot Wood's suggested code fixed the problem but I will look into this as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because your JSON is structured as an array, so you should just do:

```
NSArray *items = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSLog(@" NewsID : %@", [[items objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"newsID"]);
```

or, alternately, change the JSON itself so that it's more like:

```
{"somekeyname":[your existing json array]}
```

Comment: When I loop through these objects... should I do it in a dictionary or array?

Comment: which approach did you take? (What is the type of the line ending with JSONValue)? either way you'll loop as an array, but if it's a dictionary to start, you'll need a line to separate out the array first

Comment: `NSArray *items = [jsonString JSONValue];
for(i=0;i<items.count;i++){ NSLog(@"item %d is %@",i,[items objectAtIndex:i]);}`  ----OR-----  `NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue]; NSArray *items=[results objectForKey:@"somekeyname"];
for(i=0;i<items.count;i++){ NSLog(@"item %d is %@",i,[items objectAtIndex:i]);}`

Comment: oops, I forgot how your data was structured: `NSLog(@"item %d is %d",i,[[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"newsID"]);`